# How do I store the range of a list as a variable?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to store the range of a list as a variable but I have been having trouble researching this on-line and am stumped on how to do this. Lets say I have a list.

```
Score = [0,0,0,0]
players = #code that takes amount of different scores in the list SCORE into the variable players
```

how can I store the amount of numbers into another variable. Or use a variable to create a list with that amount of numbers.

```
print 'how many players are there'
input = () #user inputs amount of players
#code that creates list with that amount of variables
```

Comment: someone edited my question to include actual code, how do I do that?

Comment: user3475916: Edit your question yourself and see what they did to add the actual code: (hint: it has to do with the indenting of lines). When you edit a question a toolbar appears above the text edit box with icons on it you can click on after selecting text. There's also "?" icon over on the right that displays a list of topics you can select from or you can click on the [Advanced Help >>](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) link to open a new browser window showing an editing help web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Store the amount of numbers into another variable": use the builtin `len` function:

```
num_vars = len(Score)
```

To create a list of given length you have at least two options:

```
my_list = [0] * required_length
```

which gives you a list of the required length, but stores the same object in each index, which may lead to unexpected behavior with mutable objects ( **im** mutable objects are e.g. tuples, integers and strings), or the other way

```
my_list = [0 for x in range(required_length)]
```

which uses the powerful [list comprehensions](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/) and creates an individual object in each index (for mutable objects).
Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Careful with the `[x] * y` pattern on lists of lists or lists of objects, as `x` will be _the same object_ in every position, leading to strange results if you change it.

Comment: not any other initial value, it will only work with immutable objects(integers, tuples and strings)

Answer (score 0):

You could say something like this

```
print 'how many players are there'
num = int(input()) 
newList = [0]*num
```

Result for input of 5

```
>>> newList
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several good answers here that will let you initialize a list of zeros of arbitrary length. Consider though, the Pythonic way is often not to initialize something until you need it. One tool that allows this is `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
Scores = defaultdict(int)
```

`Scores` here is not a list at all, but it *does* have indexed values.

```
>>> Scores[1] += 1
>>> Scores[1]
1
```

Because the initial value of *any* score is 0, we don't need to explicitly set it, but the zeros are constructed *on demand*, so they don't take up room in memory until we need them. In addition, we have the capability to look up the score for an arbitrary player, whether that player is indexed by number or another hashable, such as string.

```
>>> Scores['david']
0
```

Well, that's to be expected, we haven't initialized David yet. But also, we didn't get an error, and we now have human-readable player names. But you can still use integers as indices if you prefer.